# AWS Cognito adminCreateUser from Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a user in a  AWS User Pool from an AWS Lambda

I tried with this script took from what seems to be the official JavascriptSDK for the AWS but can't get it working. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property

I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser is not a function

```
'use strict'
const AWS= require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

    var params = {
        UserPoolId: 'eu-west-1_XXXXXXXX', /* required */
        Username: 'me@example.com', /* required */
        DesiredDeliveryMediums: [
            'EMAIL'
        ],
        ForceAliasCreation: false,
        MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
        TemporaryPassword: 'tempPassword1',
        UserAttributes: [
            {
                Name: 'email', /* required */
                Value: 'me@example.com'
            },
            {
                Name: 'name', /* required */
                Value: 'Me'
            },
            {
                Name: 'last_name', /* required */
                Value: 'lastme'
            }
            /* more items */
        ]
    };
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        callback(null, data);
    });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the issues. You're getting this error because Lambda isn't currently running their execution environment with the most recent JS SDK. Until that is updated, you should be able to work around this by manually pulling in the most recent version.