# AWS Cognito adminCreateUser from java script SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a user in a AWS User Pool from an AWS Lambda

I tried with this script took from what seems to be the official JavascriptSDK for the AWS but can't get it working. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property

I keep getting this error:ypeError: cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser is not a function

```
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

var params = {
    UserPoolId: 'eu-west-1_XXXXXXXX', /* required */
    Username: 'me@example.com', /* required */
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: [
        'EMAIL'
    ],
    ForceAliasCreation: false,
    MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
    TemporaryPassword: 'tempPassword1',
    UserAttributes: [
        {
            Name: 'email', /* required */
            Value: 'me@example.com'
        },
        {
            Name: 'name', /* required */
            Value: 'Me'
        },
        {
            Name: 'last_name', /* required */
            Value: 'lastme'
        }
        /* more items */
    ]
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    callback(null, data);
});
```

Comment: What is the AWS variable assigned to in your example? Is is `const AWS = require('aws-sdk');` ? And do you have that line and the first of your lines outside the function itself? It should not be part of the function.

Comment: For those who copy these attributes: the attribute last_name doesn't exist, it should be family_name!

Answer (score 5):

For adminCreateUser (you basically require the aws sdk, configure credentials, instantiate the client and call the specific operation).

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({accessKeyId: 'akid', secretAccessKey: 'secret'});

var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider;
var client = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19 });
//your code goes here
```

Note that there might be different ways in which you can configure the AWS credentials to call the operation. You do need credentials as this is an authenticated operation. Other admin operations are similar, you just need to pass the appropriate parameters as JSON in the call.

According to this, the AWS SDK for JavaScript version 2.7.25 which contains the adminCreateUser operation should be available.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Comment: Where is `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` ?

Comment: Here are the docs referring to handling credentials in Javascript: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html

Answer (score 0):

Try bundling the latest aws-sdk into your uploaded package instead of relying on the one made available by default.

Source: [AWS Cognito adminCreateUser from Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475380/aws-cognito-admincreateuser-from-lambda/42243314)